# How can I traverse through these data in order to fetch information from it

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am calling weather api and it responded with the data. I am able to get some data out of the object but when i tried to fetch certain data it give me object error in React.

```
class Weather extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weatherData: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Brampton,ca&units=metric&mode=json`)
      .then(res => {
        const weatherData = res.data;
        this.setState({ weatherData });
      })
  }
  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        WetherData<br/>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData)}
        <ul>
          <li>{this.state.weatherData.name}</li>
          <li>{JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.weather)}</li>

          </ul>
      </div>  
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Raw Data

```
"coord":{"lon":-79.76,"lat":43.69},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":10.06,"pressure":1017,"humidity":81,"temp_min":7.78,"temp_max":12.22},"visibility":24140,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":10},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1556908224,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1002,"message":0.0067,"country":"CA","sunrise":1556878127,"sunset":1556929377},"id":5907364,"name":"Brampton","cod":200}
```

{JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.weather)} I get the data here.

but when i try

{JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.weather.main)} it gives me object error.

or
if i  try

{JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.coord)} it works

but

{JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.coord.lon)} gives me an object error

Comment: JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.weather[0].main and you don't need to stringify the longitude; its just a number you can directly print it as this.state.weatherData.coord.lon

Comment: `weather` (and thus `this.state.weatherData.weather`) is an array, so you can't use `.main` on that. `this.state.weatherData.weather[0].main` should do the trick, so you'll probably want to iterate over all elements inside that array, unless you can be sture that there's always only one element inside of it. I don't see the problem with `coord.lon` however.

Comment: I have tried options you have mentioned here. but does not seems to be working.
here is the codepen link [https://codepen.io/vishangsoni/pen/MRNGvM] codepen